# how to make a fixed portion of scroll activity to display on every screen sizes

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, android-scrollview

How can I make a fixed portion of a scroll activity display on every screen size?
I have a scrollable activity which contains a pageviewer, and below that, 4 buttons. On an average screen it just displays only these things, the rest comes below the screen, which means there are few more views below the button. If we use a wider screen, then these views also appear in main view before scrolling. I need to make the view range the same for all screen sizes, meaning for wider screen also, I need to just view the pageviewer and buttons only, the rest should be seen only when we scroll.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/idd_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewPager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="500dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="1">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25"
                    android:text="Button1" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25"
                    android:text="Button1" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25"
                    android:text="Button1" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25"
                    android:text="Button1" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="other view" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="other view" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="other view" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="other view" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="other view" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

set ViewPager height programatically so it can match mobile height

Comment: i tried to set ViewPager height programaticallyto match mobile height but i cant get a rigth way to do it